Is it valid to call std::destroy_at on a unconstructed object?
When I was reading the sample code of std::construct_at at cppref, I noticed that std::destroy_at is called on a uninitialized buffer:
alignas(S) unsigned char storage[sizeof(S)]{};
S uninitialized = std::bit_cast<S>(storage);
std::destroy_at(&uninitialized);

I somehow believed that this should be UB operation because lifecycle of object is not started yet. Is calling std::destroy_at on an uninitialized buffer a valid operation by c++ standard?

Note std::bit_cast will start the lifetime of uninitialized (thus the constructor of S has been called)

It's not calling it on the buffer, it's calling it on the result object of std::bit_cast - any potential UB would first be there. And if the result is not undefined, then we call destroy_at on an object within its lifetime.

This boils down to S x = ...; std::destroy_at(&x);, bit_cast is a red herring. This by itself isn't UB, but the automatic destructor call for x at the end of scope is UB if the object is already dead, I believe.

It's not clear why the example even has storage - its only purpose seems to be to potentially cause UB in the bit-cast.  It would be better to start with a constructed S and std::destroy_at() that.

It's wrong to call std::destroy_at on an unconstructed object - that would be UB.
But that's not what's happening here.  It's being called on the S object at uninitialized, not on storage.  The latter seems to be a red herring - there's no good reason for constructing uninitialized from random bytes rather than simply aggregate-initializing it.
A clearer example would omit the red-herring storage variable:
S uninitialized{0, 0.0f, 0.0};
std::destroy_at(&uninitialized);


There is a real bug in the example: we have
std::destroy_at(ptr);

and ptr points to uninitialized.  So at end of scope, we have a second destruction of the same object, which is UB.
If that line is removed, the example becomes valid.

even if we write it like S uninitialized{0, 0.0f, 0.0}; std::destroy_at(&uninitialized);, at the end of scope destructor for unintialized will be called again which is UB?isn't it?

Yes, that's right if we don't std::construct_at() in its place.  That's the bug I describe in the second half of the answer.

I think that's a very poor sample code, and it should probably be rewritten from scratch.

@TobySpeight "if we don't std::construct_at() in its place" - the cppref example is doing exactly that (it just wasn't shown in the question), but then it calls destroy_at again, so the problem still exists

@Remy, yes, that's the destroy_at I refer to.

The example given on cppref is actually well defined as is. S has a trivial destructor and as such there is no requirement for uninitialized to be within its lifetime at block exit. - This is covered by 6.7.3 basic.life (9):

If a program ends the lifetime of an object of type T with static, thread, or automatic storage duration and if T has a non-trivial destructor, the program must ensure that an object of the original type occupies that same storage location when the implicit destructor call takes place; otherwise the behavior of the program is undefined. — So there is no need to "resurrect" trivially destructible variables before exiting the block; this would only be UB if S had a non-trivial destructor.
